# Can in insert data multiple times into a bucketed hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, bucket

I have a bucketed hive table. It has 4 buckets.

```
CREATE TABLE user(user_id BIGINT, firstname STRING, lastname STRING)
COMMENT 'A bucketed copy of user_info'
CLUSTERED BY(user_id) INTO 4 BUCKETS;
```

Initially i have inserted some records into this table using the following query.

```
set hive.enforce.bucketing = true;
insert into user
select * from second_user;
```

After this operation In HDFS I see that 4 files are created under this table dir.

Again i needed to insert another set of data into user table. So i ran the below query.

```
set hive.enforce.bucketing = true;
insert into user
select * from third_user;
```

Now another 4 files are crated under user folder dir. Now it has total 8 files.

Is this fine to do this kind of multiple inserts into a bucketed table?
Does it affect the bucketing of the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out!!
Actually if you do multiple inserts on a bucketed hive table. Hive wont complain as such.
All hive queries will work fine.

Having said that, Such operation spoils the bucketing concept of the table. I mean after multiple inserts into a bucketed table the sampling fails.

The TABLASAMPLE doesnt work properly after multiple inserts.

Even sort merge bucket map join also doesnt work after such operation.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that should be a issue because you have declared that you want bucketing on user_id. so every time you would insert it will create 4 more files.

Bucketing is used for faster query processing so if it is making 4 more files everytime it will be making your query processing even faster.

Comment: thanks for the response. do you have any supporting documents. just to be sure. I have searched a lot. didnt find any